# Manually check requests on port in kdb

Tags: kdb

From what I understand the main q thread monitors it socket descriptors for requests and respond to them.

I want to use a while loop in my main thread that will go on for an indefinite period of time. This would mean, that I will not be able to use `hopen` on the process port and perform queries.

Is there any way to manually check requests within the while loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to use a while loop? Is there any chance you could, for instance, instead use the [timer](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zts-timer) functionality of KDB+?

This could allow you to run a piece of code periodically instead of looping over it continually. Depending on your use case, this may be more appropriate as it would allow you to repeatedly run a piece of code (e.g. that could be polling something periodically), without using the main thread constantly.

KDB+ is by default single-threaded, which makes it tricky to do what you want to do. There might be something you can do with [slave threads](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/cmdline/#-s-slaves).

If you're interested in using timer functionality, but the built-in timer is too limited for your needs, there is a more advanced set of timer functionality available free from AquaQ Analytics (disclaimer: I work for AquaQ). It is distributed as part of the TorQ KDB framework, the specific script you'd be interested in is [timer.q](https://github.com/AquaQAnalytics/TorQ/blob/master/code/common/timer.q), which is documented [here](http://aquaqanalytics.github.io/TorQ/utilities/#timerq). You may be able to use this code without the full TorQ if you like, you may need some of the other "common" code from TorQ to provide functions used within timer.q